# PHP Location function to check $_GET

Tags: php, mysqli

Come to a little problem here with location direct.
Got a page where user NEEDS to have the correct "code" to access the page, those links is shared by URL`s like http://www.domain.com/index.php?c=65487549
If user comes to this page without the ?c= or just plain filename index.php
they should be sent to another place.

What i have tried so far:

```
    if (!isset($_GET['c']) == "") {
                header ('Location: http://www.domain.com/another.php');
                exit();
    } else {
        $result2 = $link->query('SELECT code FROM Codes WHERE code="'.    (isset($_GET['c'])).'"');
    $CodeisValid = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

        if ($CodeisValid) {
          return true;
        } else {
                header ('Location: http://www.domain.com/another.php');
                exit();
        }
    }
```

If user has the correct code from db, user should see the page.

Any clue ?

Thanks =)

Comment: `if (!isset($_GET['c']) == "")` that's a false positive; you need to break those up into two separate conditions. You're also open to an sql injection.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok, thanks. sql injection i was planning to get before going live, but thanks for letting me know :-)

Comment: Please read and understand what `isset()` does and how it works: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 1):

I would write the code like this:

```
// remove unallowed characters from user input
$code = (int) $_GET['c']; // this will make sure your code is an integer. If you use other characters use `preg_replace` instead.
// There are many ways to sanitize the input here

// if is empty redirect user
if (empty($code)) {
    header('Location: http://www.domain.com/another.php');
    die;
}

$result2 = $link->query('SELECT code FROM Codes WHERE code = "'. $code .'" LIMIT 1');
$CodeisValid = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

if ($CodeisValid !== 0) {
    return true;
} else {
    header ('Location: http://www.domain.com/another.php');
    die;
}
```

Is always better to sanitize the user input. No matter how you get it, from forms, from GET, POST, etc. Always sanitize the user input.

When you need only one result from database limit your query, this will speed up things considerately.

Always use strict comparisons in if statements. Why ? Run the following code and you'll see why:

```
<?php
if ('string' == 0) {
    echo 'you got me';
}
```

If you use the strict comparison `===` the if will work as it should to.

Later edit:

This is wrong

```
'SELECT code FROM Codes WHERE code="'.    (isset($_GET['c'])).'"';
```

because `isset` will return a boolean (true or false) which inside string will be translated as `1` if is true and as `''` empty string if is not set which in any case will be a bug generator

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of my code! I tried your way as well, but getting this then: Notice: Undefined index: c in /home/2/v/www/index.php on line 5 Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/2/v/www/index.php:5) in /home/2/v/www/index.php on line 10

Comment: You may use the notice suppressor `(int) @$_GET['c'];` but is not recommended. You could also have this code in a function or a class method and return true if the code is found and false is not found in the database. if the return is false, then you can make the redirect. So you can add some tests to it

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this situation. What I would propose is

```
if (empty($_GET['c'])) {
            header ('Location: http://www.domain.com/another.php');
            exit();
} else {
    $result2 = $link->query('SELECT code FROM Codes WHERE code="'.    (isset($_GET['c'])).'"');
$CodeisValid = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

    if ($CodeisValid) {
      return true;
    } else {
            header ('Location: http://www.domain.com/another.php');
            exit();
    }
}
```

I think this will do the job. If not please comment. Hope it helps

Comment: Tried your code, thanks, but gives me Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/2/v... Almost same message as before unfortanly :-)

Comment: Thanks for trying out the code. I think the error is with in the else part. When you pass the c value, in the query `SELECT code FROM Codes WHERE code="'.    (isset($_GET['c'])).'` change it to `SELECT code FROM Codes WHERE code="'.    ($_GET['c']).'` I think the redirection must have worked. Did it?

Comment: The redirection work like a charm :-) But when a user comes to the page with nothing after .php then white page unfortanly.

Comment: Add an !isset($_GET['c']) to the if condition.  'if (empty($_GET['c']) || !isset($_GET['c'])) '

Answer (score 0):

Just remove  **== ""** in the first row of your code.
And in the query remove "**isset**" from there.

isset is checking if the variabile "is set" - if exists. It returns only TRUE or FALSE, so in the query you won't be looking for FALSE or TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution i guess, but this one worked just like i asked.
With nothing after .php redirect user.
With nothing or wrong code after ?c= redirect user.
If correct code, show page.

If anyone has a better version, I'm happy for all help :-)

```
    if (empty($_GET['c'])) {
        header ('Location: http://www.domain.com');
      die();
    } 

    if (isset($_GET['c'])) {
        $GetCode = htmlspecialchars($_GET['c']);

        $result = $link->query('SELECT code FROM FF_Products WHERE code = "'. $GetCode .'" LIMIT 1');
        $CodeisValid = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($CodeisValid > 0) {
         // is valid if set return true here, only shows white page!
        } else {
          header ('Location: http://www.domain.com');
          die();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`if (!isset($_GET['c']) == "") {
    header ('Location: http://www.domain.com/another.php');
    exit();
}`

change to

`if (!isset($_GET['c']) && $_GET['c'] == "") {
    header ('Location: http://www.domain.com/another.php');
    exit();
}`

Like Fred-ii said ..

Comment: question is: "why" should they change it to that? there's a specific reason

Comment: That should be `||` not `&&`.

Comment: there's no need for that just empty($_GET['c']); will do the case